# Second coat of Quikrete High Performance Self-Leveling Resurfacer

Tags: concrete

I've just poured a first coat of Quikrete High Performance Self-Leveling Resurfacer and have irregularities due to not pouring each bucket fast enough for the area I'm resurfacing (250 sf) and, i think, that the water:concrete ratio was too thick to flow. Perhaps due to the relatively low humidity where i am?). I need to level the first coat.

I submitted a support request on Quickrete's site but no response yet.

Can i pour a second skim coat?
How long can i wait? Or must i wait?
Is any additional surface prep required?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The OP added this in a comment:

> I never heard back from Quikrete from the email support request so
>   called the customer support number and the guy was very helpful.
>
> Answer: Yes. Multiple coats can be applied. Restrictions - wait 24
>   hours. Pour additional applications up to 1".
>
> I was envisioning the stuff freely flowing all over the floor like
>   water, but it's cement. Mistakes I made:
>
> 1. Not having maximum amount pre-mixed and ready to pour (literally) at once.
> 2. Underestimating amount of material I needed.
> 3. Trying to smooth it with a floor squeegee. Don't touch it!
> 4. A bit too thick